# Mount - Problem Remounting /dev/sdb1

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem

How can I properly remount `/dev/sdb1`? Because when I remount it:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected
```

...displaying that it is write protected. Before this happened, it is read and writable, but when I connected it to my laptop, it just got this, read-only file system. 
I retry to mount and change its file system/permissions. But it doesn't change..
Need help please...

Comment: I got the exact same error message with a disk drive in a desktop I was moving daily. My issue ended up being a loose sata cable.
Fixing the cable and rebooting fixed that exception for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute following commands in terminal.

```
id user_name
```

replace user_name with your user name to get your uid then execute this command

```
sudo mount -o rw,uid=your_uid_here /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

replace your_uid with uid of your user found above.

Comment: I try it and then it displays:                                     Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: okay then unmount it first. sudo umount /dev/sdb1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I've un-mounted and then re-mounted with `rw` and my `uid` but still it's a read-only system...

Comment: i used this command on `sda1`. After unknown error that trigger  `errors=remount-ro`.  and after `sudo mount -o rw,uid=1000 /dev/sda1 /mnt` - i got `mount: /mnt: /dev/sda1 already mounted on /.`. so this didnot work for me

Comment: Actually I think this answer simply isn't correct as I see the same error message (from the question) when I run the command as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try `umount` and then `mount` as easy like it sounds

`umount /point_of_mount`

`mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /point_of_mount`

Thats worked for me

Comment: "Thats worked for me": So you did have the same problem? What was causing the problem in your case?

Answer (score 0):

May be you filesystem is corrupted.

Check `dmesg` log (*sde* is example device):

```sh
sudo dmesg | grep sde | grep warning
```

If you see something like

```sh
[  250.726799] EXT4-fs (sde): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
```

then filesystem with errors.

Unmount filesystem:

```sh
sudo umount /path/to/mount/point
```

Then try run `e2fsck` for check and repair fs:

```sh
sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sde
```

(flag `-p` is auto mode).

But `e2fsck` may require you to run it manually, in which case be careful, you may damage or delete files and directories.

```sh
archive4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are dualbooting and Windows doesn't properly unmount its drives before shutting down.

Write a custom power off / reboot script for Windows and use that instead of the normal shutdown (or reboot) button. After doing that, I never had any issues mounting read-write for ntfs volumes anymore.

A little script like this will do:

```
@echo off
REM Unmount drive D:
mountvol D: /d

REM Shutdown the computer
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

Rename it to shutdown.bat or shutdown.cmd and double-click to poweroff. replace /t 0 with /r and it'll reboot. But when you boot in Linux, you won't have any mount issues anymore.